# Проблема с закрытием окна браузера при использовании режима дебага в PyCharm

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, test-automation

Я столкнулся с проблемой при использовании режима дебага в PyCharm для моего тестового сценария с использованием Selenium WebDriver. Во время выполнения теста отрабатывает breakpoint и далее через секунд 30 окно браузера автоматически закрывается. При чём на другом ноуте такой проблемы не наблюдается.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией или может предложить совет по устранению данной проблемы, буду благодарен за вашу помощь!

Спасибо!